# Interrupting transactions in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file-io, transactions

i am using transactions in codeigniter and have a routine includes file operations.
To be more specific i want to delete files from file system and database. I want transaction to fail if file is not found. So how can i interrupt an ongoing transaction and make it fail manually? Would

```
$this->db->trans_status() = false;
```

be enough?? Or is this approach correct way to do it?

PS: transction started in a Controller and i'm checking file status in a Model..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems it works. Except the mistake

```
$this->db->trans_status() = false;
```

must be

```
$this->db->_trans_status = false;
```